# Intercept dialog from <webview> and read the contents

Tags: webview, dialog, dart, google-chrome-app

I use this code to intercept a dialog from a webview but I can not see the content or interact with it:

```
  Element webview= querySelector("#webview");
  Map<String,String> map=new Map();
  map["src"]=urlWebView+user;
  webview.attributes.addAll(map);
  querySelector("#webview_cont").style.visibility="visible";
  window.addEventListener("dialog",(Event e){ //Use window or webview returns the same result
        e.preventDefault();
        ... //What should I do here ??
    } );
```

Any solution?
Thanks

**Edit**

Debug:

[image: Debug]

> Open issue: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23556

Comment: Have you read the documentation? I suggest you [do it again](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-dialog).

Comment: yes, but the event does not return any information about the type of dialog or text.

Comment: Try attaching the listener to the webview element, not `window`

Comment: returns exactly the same result

Comment: So you tried accessing the properties and they return undefined? I'm not familiar with Dart, but where does "Event" type come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem definitely lies with your usage of Dart's [Event class](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.Event).

It simply does not support the [extra properties](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#event-dialog) that Chrome is adding to the event: `e.dialog`, `e.messageText`, `e.messageType`.

It does not seem like there is a ready solution for that, [at least not in `chrome.dart`](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/191).

Sadly, I don't know Dart well enough to give you a solution. You need to somehow extend that event class, possibly dropping to JS level.

[This library](https://github.com/rmsmith/webview/blob/master/lib/webview.dart), even if abandoned, should give you ideas on how to do that (by catching the JS-level event and stuffing the extra properties in `CustomEvent`'s `detail` property), though implementing `DialogController` (which is not JSON-serializable) would be a bit trickier, I guess.

Comment: Why there? If anything, it should be in [`chrome.dart` issue tracker](https://github.com/dart-gde/chrome.dart/issues/). There's a _lot_ of stuff to support in `<webview>` though, like `WebRequestEventInterface`